# Descargar una foto directamente usando javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hola mi pregunta es posible descargar por ejemplo una foto directamente al abrir mi pagina web usando solamente php? lo que quiero es que cuando abra mi pagina con la foto pues se descargue para poder visualizarla en mi ordenador.
Intente con:

```
<?php header("Location: http://paginaweb/seccion1/foto.jpg"); ?>
```

Pues cuando abra esta pagina visualizare mi foto y se descargará. Pero si uso el codigo anterior mi pagina no se muestra.
Hay alguna manera de descargar una foto directamente usando php y que mi pagina se muestre?

Mi pagina sera algo simple como esto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="bgimg">
  <div class="topleft">
    <p>Logo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <h1>COMING SOON</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>35 days left</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottomleft">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creo que tienes que añadir javascript para forzar la descarga. Tu servidor genera la pagina HTML, CSS, JS... dentro de esa primera página que estas enviando al navegador ira un script (JS) que lance esa descarga.

Comment: tendría que usar un tipo MIME para forzar la descarga con javascript. tipo asi? `<iframe id="my_iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<script>
function Download(url) {
    document.getElementById('my_iframe').src = url;
};
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

No puedes al mismo tiempo desplegar el HTML y enviar un archivo para descarga. Pero respondiendo a tu pregunta, si yo quisiera que al abrir un archivo (digamos, foto.php) se descargase una imagen, sería

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/png');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mi_imagen.png"');

readfile('mi_imagen.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

Aquí esta, y lo explico en el código en sí.

```
    if (window.location.hash.substring(1) !== 'forceDownloadImage') window.addEventListener("load", forceDownload.bind(null, "m.png"));

    // Al hacer forceDownload.bind podemos pasar argumentos a la funcion en el listener.

    function forceDownload(image) {
        var d = document,
            w = window,
            a = d.createElement("A"); // creamos el elemento
        a.download = image.toString(); // Imagen a string
        a.href = "./m.png"; // href atributo
        var newTab = w.open("./#forceDownloadImage", "_blank"),
            self = newTab;
        self.addEventListener("load", _putImage);
        // Self es como el window pero de la nueva pestaña creada para poder manejar su DOM

        function _putImage() { // Funcion una vez, haya cargado totalmente la nueva pestaña
            var body = self.document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0]; // Obtenemos el Tag body de apertura
            body.appendChild(a); // Añadimos el link
            var imagen = self.document.createElement("img"); // Creamos el img
            imagen.setAttribute("src", image); // Añadimos el atributo src al tag img
            imagen.setAttribute("style", "width: 50vw; height: 50vw;"); // Atributo de tamaño de la imagen
            body.appendChild(imagen); // Añadimos la imagen
            body.appendChild(a); // Añadimos a la nueva pestaña el link para descargar
            var safe = [].slice.call(body.getElementsByTagName("A"), 0);
            // Collection HTML en array , que es lo mismo que, Array.from(collection)


            safe.forEach(elem => { // Buscamos el elemento con el link de download especificado
                    if (elem.download === image.toString()) elem.click(); // Click automatico
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var descargar = href => {
    let
    tempID = 'tempID' + new Date().getTime(),
    aDownload = document.createElement('a');
    aDownload.id = tempID;
    aDownload.href = href;
    aDownload.target = '_blanc';
    aDownload.download = href;
    document.body.appendChild(aDownload);
    document.getElementById(tempID).click();
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById(tempID));
    delete(aDownload, tempID);
};

descargar('https://www.google.com.do/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico');
// HTML: <button onclick="descargar('ruta-de-la-image')">Descargar Image</button>
```

Comment: Las publicaciones que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad, por favor edita tu respuesta para explicar qué es lo que hace le código compartido y cómo soluciona el problema expuesto. Lee [answer] para más información. Además, esto es un duplicado de la [respuesta que escribiste en otra publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/178708/250), eso suele ser una señal de que o las respuesta no es buena para una de las preguntas, o que las dos preguntas son duplicadas (en cuyo caso se debería votar como duplicado en lugar de responder).

Answer (score 0):

También puedes hacerlo simplemente con un iFrame dentro de tu página:

```
<iframe src="http://paginaweb/seccion1/foto.jpg" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Esto funciona si la ruta que mencionas realmente fuerza la descarga y no muestra la imagen, sino alterna el uso con la opción que te dio @ffflabs